# Same class name in STI, with different namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I have something like this

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
# Parent class
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
# Parent class    
end

# models/a/x.rb

class X < A

end

# models/b/x.rb

class X < B

end

# application.rb

config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**}')]
```

I need to reference X::B, but still the X from the A's namespace gets referenced. Is there anyway to achieve this, or I just need to change my X's class name?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File structure itself can't define namespace at all. You need to write the constant accordingly.

```
# models/a/x.rb
class A::X < A

# models/b/x.rb
class B::X < B
```

Also, in Rails 3 there is no need to define loading path of any files inside /app, not sure how Rails 4 works but I guess it should be similar. If so your last line is unnecessary as well.

Comment: I tried this, but it says

LoadError: Unable to autoload constant X, expected /Users/myuser/foo/app/models/a/x.rb to define it

Comment: I see, so forget my last paragraph :)

Comment: Oups, sorry you are right, It seems like it was a naming error. My models folder was called models/#{'a'.pluralize}/x.rb